# How to compare only date and year in php codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My model:

```
public function get_payscale() {
    $this->db->from('payscale P')->join('employee E','E.employee_id = P.employee_id ');
    $this->db->where('P.payscale_date',date('Y-m'));
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

I want to compare only the month and year with the db, in which the format is y-m-d, where I want only to retrieve the y-m using the `where` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this :

```
$this->db->where('EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM P.payscale_date)',date('Ym'));
```

This query will extract the Year and month from the date given column  like 201605 (2016-05-21)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure with exact syntax but something like below will work for you.

```
$this->db->where('year(Start_Date),year(curdate())');
$this->db->where('month(Start_Date),month(curdate())');
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used the same condition in core PHP you can simply implement it on Codeigniter if any issue gets while implementing let me know

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE Year('payscale_date') = 2016 and Month('payscale_date') = 05
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have datetime type in your mysql table, and if you want to grab only the year from it, use this:

```
$this->db->->where('year(prdt.date_updated)',$year);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its worked for me.

`$this->db->where('month(uspl_date)=month(curdate())');`

Comment: Please make sure to format your code