# Mysql only WHERE LIKE on month

Tags: sql

let's say i have this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(datum) FROM unique_ip WHERE (datum>='2016-02-01' AND datum<='2016-02-29')
```

I want to do a WHERE LIKE so only the month has to be specific like 01, 02 etc.  So my query is only looking for this:  ____-02-__ . How can i use WHERE LIKE in this case?

This is my Database scheme:

- ip - INT UNSIGNED - PK NOT NULL
- datum - DATE - NOT NULL (datum means date)
- Telling - INT - NOT NULL DEFAULT = 1 (Telling meaning counting)

i'd be glad to supply you with more information if needed.

Comment: `WHERE datum LIKE '%-02-%'`. By the way, Czech Republic? :)

Comment: @Rikudou_Sennin Thank you, and it's Dutch ;D

Comment: Heh, we use "datum" too :D

Comment: @Rikudou_Sennin looks like our languages have some in common indeed :0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `MONTH()` function or something like `SELECT COUNT(datum) FROM unique_ip WHERE datum LIKE '%-02-%';`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [MONTH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function.

For your query.

```
$month1 = '02';
$month2 = '02';
SELECT COUNT(datum) FROM unique_ip WHERE (MONTH(datum)>='$month1' AND MONTH(datum)<='$month2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
SELECT COUNT(datum) FROM unique_ip WHERE 
month(datum)>='month1' AND month(datum)<='month2' ;
```

Replace month1 and month2 according your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I have already answered yesterday the same question by another user. And the solution is

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE Year('payscale_date') = 2016 and Month('payscale_date') = 05
```

And question link is [how to compare only date and year in php codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996118/how-to-compare-only-date-and-year-in-php-codeigniter/37000278#37000278)

Answer (score 0):

you can format the date filed with DATE_FORMAT

```
SELECT COUNT(datum) FROM unique_ip WHERE DATE_FORMAT(datum,'%m') = '02' and DATE_FORMAT(datum,'%Y') = '2016'
```